# сборка war и uber-jar из одного проекта

Tags: java, maven

Есть проект на maven / spring, к которому требуется допилить cli-доступ для различных задач обслуживания; для этого команды должны выполняться в контексте веб-приложения. В этот момент я столкнулся с проблемой в нехватке опыта с maven: обычный плагин jar собирает jar без зависимостей, плагины shade и assembly успешно собирают проект, но при запуске java не может найти указанный в манифесте mainClass (насколько понимаю, это происходит из-за `packaging:war`).

Что у меня должно быть указано в pom.xml, чтобы один и тот же проект успешно собирался со всеми зависимостями и как jar, и как war?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд хороший подход в maven - один модуль на один артефакт.

Сделайте два дочерних maven-модуля: один для war, один для jar. Это будет проще настроить, поддерживать и расширять.

> но при запуске java не может найти указанный в манифесте mainClass (насколько понимаю, это происходит из-за packaging:war)

Само собой. В war-е классы лежат в WEB-INF/classes, а для jar-а ожидается, что в корне.

Это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
/
  /my-project-jar
    /src
    /pom.xml
  /my-project-war
    /src
    /pom.xml
  pom.xml
```

- В модуле `my-project-jar` - основной codebase и сборка jar.
- В модуле `my-project-war` - WEB-INF, web.xml, весь прочий J2EE. `my-project-jar` подключается как зависимость.
- В родительском `pom.xml` - общие переменные, версионирование, dependency management и т.п.

Comment: Боюсь, я не очень хорошо понимаю, как это должно быть организовано, чтобы весь код остался в родительском модуле (точнее, как обойтись без дублирования кода).

Comment: @Etki, обновил ответ.

Comment: сейчас попробую, отпишусь по результатам. Спасибо.

Comment: Пока работает кое-как (нельзя собрать отдельно war, не получается запустить jetty через maven), но разделил указанным сопособом.